# cancelling 1 interval on pageChange

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have 2 pages that require a function to be called every minute so I did this using `setInterval()`.  However whenever I navigate to the page a new interval is created and it eventually bogs down the site.  Is there a way to cancel an interval whenever I navigate away from a page?

```
var pollinginterval = 60000;

$('#HomeViewPage_MyLocation').live('pagebeforeshow', function(toPage, fromPage){
    GetUsersByLocation();

    setInterval(function() {
        GetUsersByLocation();
    }, pollinginterval);
});     


$('#HomeViewPage_ColleagueLocation').live('pageshow', function(toPage, fromPage){
    GetAllUsersByTeam();
    GetAvailableTeams();

    setInterval(function() {
        GetAllUsersByTeam();
        GetAvailableTeams();
    }, pollinginterval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when refreshing the browser page? Then you can stop it by listenting for `unload`:

```
var runMyFunction = function() {
  // clear interval
};

window.onunload = runMyFunction();
```

If not, you can still clear the interval on your internal page change.

Answer (score 0):

This is because jQM has a problem with multiple events. Ok it is not a problem, you must understand, in your case, each time you access your page same event is applied again.

You can do 2 things to solve this problem:

1. Instead of live use bind/unbind and on/off to unbind event before binding it again to same element after each pagebeforeshow/pageshow. This is not that good approach.

Example for click event:

```
$('#elementID').unbind();
$('#elementID').bind('click', function(e) {

});
```

1. Correct one would be to use Event filter to check if event is already bound. It can be found here: http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/event-filter/

Example for click event:

```
$('#elementID:Event(click)').each(function(){

});
```